# Why is my NSMutableArray returning nill?

Tags: cocoa

I have a very simple task:
add the contents of a textField to an NSMutableArray.The Problem is the array is returning nill. I believe that it has something to do with the fact that the array I'm using is declared as an instance variable.

```
/*
 IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
 IBOutlet NSTabView *tableView;
 IBOutlet NSButton *button;
 NSMutableArray *myArray;
 */

#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController


-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
    NSString *string = [textField stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);

    [myArray addObject:string];
    NSLog(@"%d",[myArray count]);//this outputs 0 why is that?

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633699/nsmutablearray-count-always-returns-zero

Comment: How are you initializing the array? ARE you initializing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you do the following somewhere?

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If you don't do something like that, myArray is just a null pointer and the addObject call will just silently do nothing.

---

**Edit:** The idea here is that no NSMutableArray object has been created if you just have a pointer variable.  Until the **alloc** and **init** are called, there's no object.

Check out [this CocoaDev page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSMutableArray) for more information on NSMutableArray and its use.  And the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has information on the NSMutableArray methods.

---

Also, this is essentially the same question as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633699/nsmutablearray-count-always-returns-zero).